# awk between 2 pattern search using variables does not appear to work

Tags: bash, awk

Test file

```
cat text.txt 
09:00:00 TESTING
09:00:01 TESTING
09:00:02 TESTING
09:00:03 TESTING
09:00:04 TESTING
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
09:02:01 TESTING
09:02:02 TESTING
09:02:03 TESTING
09:03:00 TESTING
09:03:01 TESTING
09:03:02 TESTING
09:03:03 TESTING
```

Actual pattern search without variables that works fine:

```
cat ./text.txt|awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '/09:01/,/09:02/' text.txt
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
```

Pattern search with variables that fails

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '/start/,/end/' text.txt
```

Nasty hack to wrap variables using shell echo that makes it work

```
echo "awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '/$start/,/$end/' text.txt"
awk -v start=09:01 -v end=09:02 '/09:01/,/09:02/' text.txt

start="09:01"; end="09:02"; echo "awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02 text.txt" '/$start/,/$end/'"|/bin/sh
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
```

Any ideas on what I be doing wrong or if this is a possible feature in awk ?

The suggestions have worked and I have had some difference in results:

1.

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0~start,$0~end' text.txt
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
```

2.

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" 'match($0,start),match($0,end)' text.txt
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
```

3.

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0~start{print}$0~end{print}' text.txt
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
09:02:01 TESTING
09:02:02 TESTING
09:02:03 TESTING
```

4.

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02"  '$1~start||$1~end' text.txt
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
09:02:01 TESTING
09:02:02 TESTING
09:02:03 TESTING
```

3 and 4 return the complete results the top two stop as soon as it hits the pattern

Comment: you can't "~" for $1 with default separator, or for $0 with anything. Let alone other data on the line, what about "02:09:01" for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the match be:

```
$ awk -F: -v hour=9 -v start=1 -v end=2 '$1==hour && $2>=start && $2<=end' file
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
09:02:01 TESTING
09:02:02 TESTING
09:02:03 TESTING
```

Don't you want all the `09:02:XX` lines?

Comment: thanks sudo - I have updated the post and shown the results from each type of awk search.

Comment: You should be clear on exactly what you want. Mine and @Thor's answers given different results, his solution gives you what you asked for (print lines from `09:01` upto the first match of `09:02`) where as mine give what you actually want (any lines with a time in between the given range).

Comment: What about this input: 19:01:01

Comment: No, I meant "$1~hour" would match against 19 (7pm) as well as 09 (9am).

Comment: Good spot *(fixed)*, you first comment didn't make it obvious what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

You need to anchor your variables to the start of the line:

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0~"^"start,$0~"^"end' text.txt
```

so that 09:02 matches 09:02:01 but not 17:09:02.

Personally I wouldn't use this range stuff but instead just set/clear/test a flag when appropriate as that's MUCH more extensible. e.g. try each of these to see how easy it is to manipulate printing or not of the delimiting lines:

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0~"^"start{f=1} f; $0~"^"end{f=0}' text.txt
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" 'f; $0~"^"start{f=1} $0~"^"end{f=0}' text.txt
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0~"^"start{f=1} $0~"^"end{f=0} f;' text.txt
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0~"^"end{f=0} f; $0~"^"start{f=1}' text.txt
```

I see from you accepting @sudo_Os answer that you may want to get all of the 09:02 times rather than stop at the first one. If that's true, just use string instead of RE comparison:

```
$ awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$1>=start":00" && $1<=end":59"' file
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
09:02:01 TESTING
09:02:02 TESTING
09:02:03 TESTING
```

or this would give the same result:

```
$ awk -F: -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$1FS$2>=start && $1FS$2<=end' file
```

Comment: Concept gets my vote. Once you've got one range of times, you'll sure need another, and another. Across 24 hours. Across a month. Across a year. By the way, is there a disadvantage in using substring($0... I've been doing it for years, but never been in touch with other AWKers :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger using substr() is fine, just not something I'd have thought to do in this situation. I tend to think of invoking functions as inefficient but in reality string concatenation in awk is inefficient too so it may not make much difference.

Comment: thanks Ed :) typically in the current environment the logs are date time so I tend to leave a space " 09:01" this way it ensures it catches 09 and not 17:09, none the less not used anchors in awk and very useful for future ref. great stuff and thanks to you all

Answer (score 2):

To use start and end as patterns you can explicitly tell awk with the `~` operator:

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" '$0 ~ start,$0 ~ end'
```

Or with `match()`:

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" 'match($0,start),match($0,end)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v start="09:01" -v end="09:02" 'substr($0,1,5) >= start && substr($0,1,5) <= end' test.txt
```

This will work when the time range spans the top of the hour, and will only look at the hours and minutes. $1 is not used, to avoid a "hit" on something that has leading blanks but otherwise matches.

To be blunt, I'd use BEGIN, and some arguments to set the start/end. Because you *can* get lots of stuff on a line, doesn't mean you have to, for me anyway.

Here is the data I used:

```
09:00:00 TESTING
09:00:01 TESTING
09:00:02 TESTING
09:00:03 TESTING
09:00:04 TESTING
09:01:00 TESTING
09:01:01 TESTING
09:01:02 TESTING
09:01:03 TESTING
09:02:00 TESTING
09:02:01 TESTING
09:02:02 TESTING
09:02:03 TESTING
09:03:00 TESTING
09:03:01 TESTING
09:03:02 TESTING
09:03:03 TESTING
02:09:01 toasted
19:01:01 toasted
  09:01:01 toasted
20:00:00 toasted 09:01:01
```

Comment: OK, so I ran it as a proper program and missed the quotes. What do you mean "semantically"?

Comment: I have used begin/ends in other types of awk statements and whilst it is good to capture lets say start and end time of the log file,  its harder to control the specific records that match the required given time.The provided statement also does work well too.  Thanks for your input.  :)